# Fingerprint reader

Tags: dell, fingerprint-reader

I bought a Dell Latitude e5470 notebook and the fingerprint reader isn't detected.
In the shop, the seller says that the fp reader is working under Linux, but the Dell support refuse me because the only supported os is Win 10 pro.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Well, there is some good news: There is a whole project at Launchpad devoted to getting fingerprint readers to work in Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui which has a program available, and is still being developed, as far as I can see.

Comment: I try it earlier but i never have succsess.